# Displaying listitems based on time

Tags: jquery, performance

I have created an audio player on my website.

There can be time based comments on tracks that are playing and I want them to be displayed when the track progress hits the timestamp of the comment.

My setup is an `ul` with the comments as `li`s. The `li`s are hidden by default. I've added the timestamp of the comments in a data-attribute of the `li`s.

Example:

```
<ul class="comments">
  <li data-timestamp="0">Check my page fans : http://www.facebook.com/ITBFLR</li>
  <li data-timestamp="185525">great sub!</li>
  <li data-timestamp="256931">@greenmono: Haha thank's dude</li>
  <li data-timestamp="497073">Wicked mix de ;)</li>
</ul>
```

There can be many comments on a track (100+). My player returns the current track progress with an interval in milliseconds.

Can I use a selector to match all `li`s with a timestamp smaller than the current track's progress?

I know there are some custom selector plugins for jQuery (e.g. [A better data selector for jQuery](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/a-better-data-selector-for-jquery/)), but I'm wondering whether that will be a huge bottleneck (performance wise).

So: would it be wise to use this solution or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Regardless of the performance of your current solution: You could create a binary search tree or a similar data structure, which lets you easily select elements smaller than a given value (key would be the timestamp, value a reference to the DOM node or just the comment which you have to insert). Or use a min heap as priority queue and always remove the first item. Maybe storing your data in such a way also lets you do other things then. Just my thoughts... :)

Comment: is there a reason you are not sorting these on the server side before you are displaying them?  It's best not to do this on the client.

Comment: @asawilliams nopez that's just me showing a bad example :P

Comment: @FelixKling How does the things work you mentioned. Both are some kind of a tree structure if I'm not mistaken. But how can I use something like that to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can always do the DOM selecting onload and save the data in an internal object. Then just fetch the relevant data whenever you need to, without touching/traversing the DOM.

Something like this might work:

```
var data = [],
    i = 0;

$(function() {
    $('.comments').find('li').each(function() {
        data.push({
            ts: this.getAttribute('data-timestamp'),
            el: $(this).hide()
        });
    });
});

onProgress(function(timestamp) { // simulated callback from the player
    while( data[i].ts < timestamp ) {
        data[i++].el.show();
    }
});
```

If I where you I would probably do it the other way around; print out the JSON data from the server, then create the list elements using JavaScript. Unless you really need the "no js" fallback...